# Google GSA Plexi Framework: Security at Serve Time: Public

Tags: google-search-appliance

Currently I am working on a Google GSA adaptor, however despite the ACLs being sent and available in the GSA. The GSA won't apply security on these documents.

The Security at Serve Time remains to public and the ACL rules aren't applied in the search results.

How is this done trough the plexi framework?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why ACLs do not get applied during serve time. If your plexi adaptor is providing the ACL to GSA, make sure it is well formed and you can check the same in the index diagnostics section for each of the record / document is sent. 
Check your flexible authorizations / policy acl settings and login mechanisms are all ok.

IMHO. This has nothing to do with plexi framework.